# How to loop a task based on it's register value in ansible

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

I have this playbook that runs a python script, which takes in an input from the user, so based on the input the user provides, the script will run successfully if the input is in the list, and it will fail if the input is not in the list and will request the user to try again until the user provides the correct input. So how do I make my ansible script interactive when user provides the wrong input?

Below is my ansible playbook:

```
   - name: Translating cc codes
      command: python3 jcl2morse.py
      args:
        chdir: /home/pi/Documents
        stdin:  "{{ userInput }}"
      register: command_output_full
      when: command_output_full.rc != 0
      loop: #Loop if current register value has no rc not equal zero
```

And here is my python function that checks in for the user input:

```
  def getInput(message):
    while True:
            try:
                    userInput = input(message)
                    if userInput not in JCL_Condition_Codes:
                            raise JCL_Exception("Error occured, invalid JCL condition code! Try again.")

            except JCL_Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    continue
            else:
                    return userInput
            break
```

Comment: i don't fully get the link between your python code and the task. Are you trying to write your own Ansible module or is that python code used somewhere else? Also, where does `userInput` comes from in your task?

Comment: I am trying to run a python script remotely  that requires an input from the user through ansible from a different server, that it is how python and ansible connect.